# How can I edit a JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, variables

Say I have a variable

```
tab_something
```

I need to drop the `tab_` bit.

In php it's easy, using `str_replace`...

Will

```
tabSelect = document.location.hash.substr(1,document.location.hash.length);
```

(which would always be `tab_something`)

```
document.write(tabSelect.replace(/tab_/i, ""));
```

Work the way I would like it to, consistently across all modern browsers (ie6+) ?

Cheers.

Comment: Referring to IE6 as a "modern browser" might be a bit of a stretch :)

Comment: The problem is IE6 is still "modernly used", much to our dismay

Comment: I know I know, I hate ie6 myself and the word modern is highly inappropriate.

Comment: "Modern" implies after the 1500s....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `document.location.hash` always contains `tab_` + some other string that you wish to retrieve, why not take advantage of the prefix always being the same length? You already have call `substring()` so why not let this function cut of a few more chars?

```
window.location.hash.substring(5)
```

Thanks to CMS for pointing out that `window.location` is preferred to `document.location`.

Answer (score 2):

Abusing source code rewrite as a substitute for reflection is … possible. I hate to state the obvious, but: maybe take a step back and see if you can reshape the project a bit, such that you can come up with a cleaner solution?

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to do any kind of source code rewriting, but the title of the question sure makes it sound that way.

Comment: That did spring to my head, however I need both variables, as tab_something, shows up a relevant div element, while something highlights it on the nav. (and yes, it should probably be the other way round)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

- `document.location` will be deprecated at some point by [`document.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.URL), consider using `window.location`.
- Consider also using [`String.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/substring), since it is part of the ECMA-262 Spec.

```
var tabSelect = window.location.hash.substring(1); // remove "#"
tabSelect = tabSelect.replace(/tab_/i, "");        // remove "tab_"
```

It will work on old and modern browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will. And also note that you don't have to use regular expressions in `.replace()`, `.replace('tab_', '');` will do just fine.

Comment: You don't even have to use replace if you know that you always want to remove the first `k` chars of the string, cf. my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is a standard JavaScript function that's been around long enough to cover all modern browsers ie6 and above. Should work just fine.

You could also use substring if you know it will always be the first 4 characters. `tabSelect.substring(4)` will give you everything starting the first character after `tab_` (it is 0-based).